# Are there any 3rd party components that let you read/create/edit PDF/Word/Excel documents in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, components

Are there any 3rd party components that let you read/create/edit PDF/Word/Excel documents in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

The .net PDF Library components from http://www.tallcomponents.com/ are very good.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the products available from [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/). There are a number of different file format components that allow you to create and manipulate PDF and Microsoft Office documents without requiring Office to be installed on the server:

> [File Format Components (Aspose)](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/default.aspx)

[Software Artisans](http://www.softartisans.com/) have some similar components that can read and write Word and Excel documents:

> [Software Artisans OfficeWriter](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/officewriter-377.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Office Web Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=982b0359-0a86-4fb2-a7ee-5f3a499515dd&displaylang=en) and [PDFLib](http://www.pdflib.com/download/free-software/pdflib-lite-7/)