# Fast and Efficient methods to read Word document not using the native Word library (Documents.Open)

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, input, ms-word

I am trying to find methods in Excel VBA that can read a large Word document containing text and tables (market research questionnaire) without opening the word document.

I realized i cannot use

```
Open file for input as #1
```

or

```
...
Open textfilename For Binary Access Read As #1
text = Space(filelength)
Get #1, , text
   
'split the file with vbcrlf
textlines = Split(text, vbCrLf) 
...
```

with Word, nor can i use ADODB as there is no connectionstring for parsing a Word document.

I read about ADO Stream, but not sure it can read and parse word files line by line.

Can someone guide me on alternative fast VBA methods to read Word files without opening them?

Comment: What do you want? Read a book not opening it? Can you reformulate your question?

Comment: @rotabor thats right. I know the traditional method of opening the workbook and reading the range or content. But i need a fast and efficient way to read the contents without opening the doc. for e.g. a docx is essentially a zip containing a word\document.xml (and other xml files). So thinking is there a method to read the contents of a zip?? Can Shell.application do that? any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you need step-by-step manual how to do it? Use Shell command to run external archiver app to unzip the docx into a temporary folder. Then 'Open file for input as #1'  where 'file' is the file with the content of the doc. Refer to docx specification.

Comment: oh, i know how to rename the docx to zip and see its contents. what i need is something like a direct access using some method. i tried shell.namespace, but it does not seem to traverse sub folders. for e.g. traverse the word folder in the zip file. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Don't use a constant as the file handler: 'Open file for input as #1'. Use FreeFile function to get the file handler. See below.

Comment: yes i know. that was just for demonstration...i use freefile.

Comment: I want to welcome @KJ's opinion to use the native Word library as the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Word COM library, you need to use a third-party library or you can directly access the file content.

To research docx file, open it in any archiver app and extract files. Then research the files. You will be able to find the text part of the document. Then you need to program this way:

1. Unzip docx in the temporary folder.
2. Get necessary file, open it and read the content.

You can refer the [format specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/728a7abc-7f55-40dc-90a7-1276ff53c8b2).

Sample code (using 7zip archiver and 'Temp' folder in the current folder):

```
Shell """C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z"" x yourdocument.docx -oTemp"
ihndlr = FreeFile()
Open "Temp\word\document.xml" For Input As #ihndlr
```

You can open the xml file in the text mode. I researched already if you need a pure text only find "w:r" tag: "<w:r>Sample text</w:r>". To process xml data you can use Microsoft XML library (mark it in project references). It provides a set of objects to manipulate xml data using DOM.

Another way is to use any third-party library, but it's very similar to use the native Word library. E. g. [Are there any 3rd party components that let you read/create/edit PDF/Word/Excel documents in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035153/are-there-any-3rd-party-components-that-let-you-read-create-edit-pdf-word-excel). You can find a lot of similar solutions https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document etc.

Comment: Updated with the sample code.

Comment: Is it clear or you need more suggestions, code samples, solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Without any example here is a DocX Invoice as table in Word and WordPad:

[image]

As XML text, it's a nest of nested layers and turns that is hard to parse reasonably easily, but as a linked or clipboard copy it maintains the OLE structure for use in Excel. Thus for data transfer from DocX to XlsX the simplest program is `Ctrl+c Ctrl+v`

[image]